# Git: Push data on branch from different folder ?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I have directory structure like below

```
papa.fit
  |__ dev
```

I have setup git for master branch where I am pushing all data except dev on master branch . but now I created sub branch say ironman where I want to push data from specific dev folder. Do i need to setup git again for dev folder ?? because `.git` is present in papa.fit and not in dev. How can i push data from dev to branch (ironman) ??

Comment: you not need to change any thing just create the dev folder in project and push it on your current branch whenever you change files in that folder it will go to that folder after commit and push

Comment: Should I push dev on another branch or put it on same master one ?

Comment: create the div folder on your same project and push it on server on same branch

Comment: is your problem is solve??

Comment: Actually the problem was something else but for a time I negotiated with your solution and moved forward.

Comment: My problem was , I wanted to make a versions on git lets say ironman is my first one then superman is second one . there is nothing different in both than extra features to superman. but I want to make a branch for each one so that whenever I want to release those feature then I can merge that sub branch to main one. can you suggest me a better way. ??